# wpf TreeViewItem bound IsSelected property not working programmatically

Tags: c#, mvvm, treeview

I'm using MVVM to bind to a tree. I'm doing this in what appears to be a fairly standard way, that is each node object in the tree supports an ITreeNode interface:

```
public interface ITreeNode
{
    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<ITreeNode> Children { get; }

    ITreeNode Parent { get; set; }

    string Name {get;}
}
```

The xaml defines a simple HierachicalDataTemplate:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

And then I define an ItemContainerStyle to bind the IsExpanded and IsSelected properties

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

My issue is, if I programatically change the IsSelected property, the tree does not reflect the new selection.  If I make the selection using the mouse then the IsSelected Property is updated just fine.  I added an event into the setter for the IsSelected property and I can see that when I make a selection with the mouse, I correctly get 2 calls to the IsSelected Setter, the first false to deselect the existing item and the second True for the newly selected node.  When I do it programatically, I only get the single call, which sets the value to true.  I've tried manually setting the old node to false, but it makes not he slightest difference.

The IsExpanded property is working just fine. In fact, if I try to select a node several layers down, the calls to expand all the parent nodes so that the node can be seen, all works just fine, however, the actual node is not selected.

I've been through the code a dozen times and it looks fine, what could be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your concrete implementation of ITreeNode.

Comment: This problem has gone away with no code changes! After hours of hunting it down, I started getting glitches in Visual Studio, so I cleaned the project, deleted the cached obj files and restarted VS, then it worked just fine!